# digitally sign just the executable, or all assemblies? (from an antivirus point of view)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, digital-signature, antivirus

I have a digital signing certificate in order to sign my application. My installation setup kit (the .msi) is now digitally signed. My application (the .exe) is also digitally signed.

An antivirus will check all sorts of activity for unsigned apps (making them slower). Knowing my application is digitally signed, do I need all my other assemblies signed as well, in order for the antivirus not to slow it down?

(notes: my app needs really low latency, so anything slowing it down is not good; I did look into the other similar questions, but none address the antivirus)

Comment: It would depend quite a bit on what antivirus software you're concerned about. If my antivirus application omitted checks just because an application was signed, I'd ask for a refund. It also seems more obvious to test this for yourself instead of relying on testimonies from random people on the internet.

Comment: I understand where you're coming from. I don't mind any checks at the startup of the app or so, or maybe when accessing the internet, I just don't want it slowing me down.

Comment: The point is, for obvious reasons, there are no switches or signs that will convince all anti-virus software to leave out checks that might impact performance, because if there were malicious applications would simply abuse them. From a trustworthiness perspective, a certificate shows someone has paid for a certificate and nothing more. If you're very unlucky, your anti-virus could slow things down while doing redundant certificate checks, so you're worse off than if you hadn't signed your code. (This would be bad, but anti-virus software often *is* bad.) Testing is king.